# Htaccess rewrite localhost/website/index.php?pages=pages/login.php to localhost/website/login

Tags: .htaccess, url

I want to rewrite `localhost/website/index.php?pages=pages/login.php` to `localhost/website/login`

This was my attempt, when i open `localhost/website/login` it says 404 not found

````
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Domain/

#Make sure it's an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
#Make sure its a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pages=pages/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```
````

Comment: You forgot to explain what error or unexpected behaviour occurs when you run the code currently. See also [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue. Also, "I want" isn't a question. Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options -Multiviews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /website/login
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?pages=pages/login.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hello, I don't know exactly what you want to do, but try this